# Aggregate dynamically a list of dynamically created columns in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have added a list (over 100) of columns to a dataframe dynamically. The columns with negative numbers are those columns which were generated from the value of the bookID column. In each row, only one of the dynamic columns has value of 1 and the rest of the columns will be 0. I need to combine the rows that have the same first 3 columns. Column bookId needs to be aggregated to include the values of the of the columns that are set to 1 and that aggregate is working.  The dynamic libraries need to be aggregated in a way that if any of the dynamic columns are set to 1 in any rows, it will be set to 1, otherwise 0.  How to aggregate the sum of the columns dynamically?

```
columns = ["name", "last", "address", "bookID"]
books = [-23, -44, -97, -32, -57, -76]
for book in books:
    df = df.withColumn(str(book), when(df['bookID'] == book, lit(1)).otherwise(0)) 

|      name|     last| address|bookID|-23|-44|-97|-32|-57|-76|
+----------+---------+--------+------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|firstname1|lastname1|address1|   -97|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|firstname1|lastname1|address1|   -23|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|firstname2|lastname2|address2|   -23|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|firstname2|lastname2|address2|   -76|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|
```

expected Outcome:

```
|      name|     last| address|bookID_values|-23|-44|-97|-32|-57|-76|
+----------+---------+--------+-------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|firstname1|lastname1|address1|   [-97, -23]|  1|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|firstname2|lastname2|address2|   [-23, -76]|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|
```

I am creating an array of statements and passing them as a parameter to the agg function, but I am getting [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN_WITH_SUGGESTION] error.

```
agg_exps= [collect_list("bookID").alias("bookID_values"),]
s = ""
for book in books:
    column_name = str(book)
    s=f"(sum('{column_name}' == 1, lit(1).otherwise(lit(0)))).alias('{column_name}')"
    agg_exps.append(col(s))
      
agg_df = df.groupBy("name", "last", "address").agg(*agg_exps)
```

I have also tried other ways such as:
 `s=f"when(sum('{column_name}' == 1, lit(1).otherwise(lit(0)))).alias('{column_name}')"`

Comment: You can just take a max for `books` columns.

Answer (score 1):

Let us fix your code:

```
agg_exps = [
    F.collect_list('bookID').alias('bookID'),
    *[F.max(str(book)).alias(str(book)) for book in books]
]
df1 = df.groupBy("name", "last", "address").agg(*agg_exps)
```

---

```
df1.show()
+----------+---------+--------+----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|      name|     last| address|    bookID|-23|-44|-97|-32|-57|-76|
+----------+---------+--------+----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|firstname1|lastname1|address1|[-97, -23]|  1|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|firstname2|lastname2|address2|[-23, -76]|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|
+----------+---------+--------+----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: It worked like champ.  Thank you so much.  I should have posted this days ago. It would have saved me days of work!

Comment: Happy coding..~